# 2D array in python all column values being set

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 5x5 2D array within a dictionary with all values set to False.

For some reason, when I do this statement with x = 2 and y = 1:

```
dict[key][x][y] = True
```

The second columns all contains True and not just the element at (2, 1).

Edit: This is how I make the array:

```
dict[key] = [[False] * width] * height
```

Comment: How are you making the arrays?

Comment: When you make the array like that all the arrays you have multiple references to the same array in memory. When you change one, you see it in all of them. `d['key'][1] is d['key'][2]` --> `True`

Comment: Instead use `[[False for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]`

Comment: @Raj, you can get away with `[[False] * width for j in range(height)]` right?